# I want Disable Drag. When drop image to target and insert to database

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".Shops").draggable({ revert: 'invalid'});
    $('#inventory').droppable();
    $('#slot2').droppable({ accept: '.Shops'});
    $('#slot1').droppable({ accept: '.Shops'});
    $('#slot2,#slot1,#inventory').bind('drop', function(ev,ui) { itemInSpot(ui.draggable,this); });

});
```

I want Disable Drag. When drop image to target and insert to database

Comment: what do you mean ? you can comment out the drag & drop code and the feature will be gone.

Comment: I think you need to set some 'flags' for yourself.  Check to see if the image(s) are actually dropped in that div or area (i.e. the database) if it is, flags are thrown and then the information associated with that image are inserted into the database.  i think you're trying to do it in too few steps.